# Parsing error: Unexpected token => with Linter(Travis CI)

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, linter

I have this code, but Travis CI keeps denying it when I push up to GitHub because of the `=>`, but I am not sure how to rewrite it so it will pass. Also, I do have es6 listed as true in my linter file

```
 bcrypt.compare(password, hash, err, pwMatches) => {
     console.log("I'm the password manager", pwMatches);
 }
```

Comment: The arrow function lacks the argument part. Function call is the place where to define values for the arguments, argument list in the function definition defines the names of the arguments.